# Kotlin how to combine different receivers via with clause without repeating it

Tags: search, kotlin, syntax, parent-child, kotlin-extension

I have Parent-Search-Child system as below:

```
class Room

class Building {
    fun find(by: By) = Room()
}

sealed class By {

    abstract fun search(): Room

    class ById(id: String) : By() {
        override fun search(): Room = Room() // epic search method
    }

    class ByName(name: String) : By() {
        override fun search(): Room = Room() // epic search method
    }

    class Byurpose(purpose: String) : By() {
        override fun search(): Room = Room() // epic search method
    }

    companion object {
        fun id(id: String) = ById(id)
        fun name(name: String) = ByName(name)
        fun purpose(purpose: String) = Byurpose(purpose)
    }
}
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
val building = Building()
val room = building.find(By.name("Toilet"))
```

However, I am not very satisfied with the current syntax, which could be much less verbose in Kotlin. In addition, `building.find` can appear **thousands** times in the code. I could implement it differently, but actually I don't own `Room`, `Building` or `By` classes, so I can't. Thus this was my  approach:

I implemented context class that stores `Building` reference, and use it internally as source for search methods:

```
class BuildingContext(private val building: Building) {
    fun String.findById() = building.find(By.id(this))
    fun String.findByName() = building.find(By.name(this))
    fun String.findByPurpose() = building.find(By.purpose(this))
}
```

It can be used as below:

```
with(BuildingContext(building)) {
    val room2 = "Toilet".findByName()
}
```

After that I noticed that I only use one search method in 99% cases, so (for sake of even shorter syntax!) I implemented following classes:

```
object AlwaysSearchById {
    fun String.find(building: Building) = building.find(By.id(this))
}

object AlwaysSearchByName {
    fun String.find(building: Building) = building.find(By.name(this))
}

object AlwaysSearchByPurpose {
    fun String.find(building: Building) = building.find(By.purpose(this))
}
```

Which can be used this way:

```
with(AlwaysSearchByName) {
    val room3 = "Toilet".find(building)
}
```

Unfortunately, building reference appears again. The ideal syntax would be `"Toilet".find()`. I could fix it re-implementing `Always~` classes as follows:

```
class AlwaysSearchByNameV2(private val building: Building) {
    fun String.find() = building.find(By.name(this))
}
```

And it would be used as below:

```
with(AlwaysSearchByNameV2(building)) {
    val room = "Toilet".find()
}
```

But it some cases, I would like to access `BuildingContext` methods as well, so So I have to write:

```
with(BuildingContext(building)) {
    with(AlwaysSearchByNameV2(building)) {
        val toilet = "Toilet".find()
        val randomRoom = "123".findById()
    }
}
```

---

### **The question is - How I reduce multiple `with` clauses in this case?**

In the example above there are only 2 `with` clauses, but it's only basic example. In real world there could be dozens of them, and writing `with(with(with(with(with...` would surely be a pain.

*On the side note this doesn't work:*

```
with(BuildingContext(building), AlwaysSearchByNameV2(building)) {
    val toilet = "Toilet".find()
    val randomRoom = "123".findById()
}
```

*nor this*

```
with(*arrayOf(BuildingContext(building), BuildingContext(building))) {
    val toilet = "Toilet".find()
    val randomRoom = "123".findById()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom scoping functions instead of relying on `with` all the time. For example you can add an extension function that will run a block of code in scope of `AlwaysSearchByNameV2` object:

```
inline fun BuildingContext.byName(f : AlwaysSearchByNameV2.() -> Unit) = AlwaysSearchByNameV2(building).apply(f)
```

And use it:

```
with(BuildingContext(building)) {  // this: BuildingContext
    byName {  // this: AlwaysSearchByNameV2
        val toilet = "Toilet".find()
        val randomRoom = "123".findById()  // can still refer to BuildingContext
    }
    // back to this: BuildingContext
}
```